# What is the outcome in javascript with multiple librarys that use $

Tags: javascript, dollar-sign

Let's pretend this is in the `<head>` of your html page.

**OOPS this was a bit that was missing before...**:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/include/js/billys.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/include/js/susies.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/include/js/marys.js"></script>
```

Order of the 3 scripts could vary.  What would be the outcome?

Billy defines `$` as

```
function $ () {
 return false;
}
```

Susie defines `$` as

```
function $ () {
 return document.getElementById('body');
}
```

Mary defines `$` as

```
function $ () {
 alert('I wrote this');
}
```

Comment: Sorry, see the question now.  I'm talking with external js files.  Just to be clear.

Comment: as i said in my answer. whatever is last, is the definition of `$`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Whatever is **last** is the final definition of `$`

That is why in (for example) jQuery there is `noConflict()` which lets you use a different variable than `$` for jQuery

Comment: So it is ALWAYS [ALWAYS], top down, and whatever is last is what it will use?

Comment: I'm confirming that you are saying the order of the scripts is really all that matters.

Comment: not unless you have a `setTimeout(function(){window.$=undefined;},100);` or `window.onload` defining the function :P

Answer (score 16):

[Why not try it?](http://jsfiddle.net/hP3HY/)

```
function $ () {
 return false;
}
function $ () {
 return document.getElementById('body');
}
function $ () {
 alert('I wrote this');
}
$(); // alerts "I wrote this"
```

The later definition overwrites the existing one.  This is why it's generally good practice to check whether a function already exists before defining it. e.g.

```
if (typeof $ !== 'function') {
    function $(){ /* your code */}
}
```

or to fail in some sensible way.

Comment: If the function exists, overwrite it with a blank function? I think you need to change your last example a bit.

Comment: @minitech Um, yeah, `!==` is what I meant. Comment added for clarity.

Comment: @Joel Good stuff- added to the answer.

Comment: I didn't use Jsfiddle since my question had to do with multiple external js files. I had accidentally posted the question with that bit missing at first..

Comment: @Doug Well, it's all the same thing. Multiple script tags are parsed sequentially, whether they're inline or external, and they are effectively one file.

Answer (score 5):

The last function with the same name wins.